# Docker Compose: Database Connection Error on 1st run, not on subsequent runs

Tags: database, docker, docker-compose

When composer runs first time `docker compose -f docker-compose-dev.yaml up --build`, it throws DB connection error, but subsequent run does not. That's is, press `ctrl+c` to abort the run. Run same command again, it will not give  error. So my question is why first time it throws error but not on subsequent runs. Here is my `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml.` file. To reproduce the error, delete volume and DB container. Run command, it will again throw the error. Even when I run script as it is given in (Part 8: Use Docker Compose) under (Get Started) of Docker documentation, it shows same error.

**Dockerfile**

```
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --production
COPY . .
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  sgweb:
    build:
      context: .
    ports: 
    - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
    - sgdb
    environment:
    - MYSQL_HOST=sgdb
    - MYSQL_USER=root
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    - MYSQL_DB=get-started-build

  sgdb:
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes: 
    - db-get-started:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=get-started-build

volumes:
  db-get-started:
```

Tried `depends_on`, placed DB block first, deep dived syslog to find out the issue, and many more, but no result.

Comment: This symptom sounds like your application is trying to connect to the database before it's fully ready.  Does [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) help you?